# BSOD after Creator's Update

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-10-v1703

The other day I had to restart my Windows 10 Home PC, and the Start menu restart button said "Update and restart" ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4asr.png)). I suspect this was the Creator's Update because I've been pushing it off, and the last notification I got said something to the effect of "This is your last opportunity to postpone the update."

So I hit "Update and Restart" and Windows began the update process: "Getting things ready", etc. In middle of updating, I got the blue screen of death and it restarted. Now it is stuck in a reboot loop, ending in a BSOD with error: "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE". I googled around and apparently this is a pretty common stop code. I can access the drive and see all the files just fine from the Recovery Environment command prompt and from various LiveCDs.

Here's what I've tried so far from the RE and the corresponding results, per online advice I found:

- Safe mode: Results in same BSOD
- Startup Repair: "Startup repair couldn't repair your pc". It also provides a path to a log file for the startup repair, and one line in that file is this: "**Root cause found: A patch is preventing the system from starting.**"
- Revert to previous build: something along the lines of, "We are unable to revert to last build"
- System restore: No restore points found.
- `bootrec`: `/scanos` results in "Total identified Windows installations: 0". I followed the instructions here (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec.exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues) to export, delete and rebuild the BCD store. After I did that, it found my Windows installation, but it didn't stick. Restarting gave same BSOD, and running `/scanos` again showed 0 again.
- `dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` : Returns "Error: 0x800f082f An error occurred reverting the pending actions from the image."

Any suggestions? I'm currently cloning the drive to an external drive using Hiren's BootCD. So if I need to reinstall Windows I should have all my data, but I'd still like to avoid it if possible...

Comment: Your going to need to reinstall Windows.The fact the update that caused this was a feature update was actually just bad luck.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. Have you seen this happen before? Are you saying this can theoretically happen with ANY MS hotfix? That seems incredibly unreliable and risky, on MS's part. Also if you have any more input on how exactly you think this occurred I'd be curious to hear it.

Comment: Yes; it happened to me; I decided to replace my hdd

Comment: @ramhound wait, you mean it was a hardware problem? I don't think that's the case for me...

Comment: No; I decided to replace the hdd rather then format it.