# Inaccessible Boot Device Bluescreen after Security Update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

When I turned off my PC yesterday, it seems that my Windows 10 installed a security update. But today, when turning on my PC, I'm getting **Inaccessible Boot Device** bluescreen. And no, I didn't install or uninstall anything new (no new hardware or software). It was simply the Windows Update that wrecked my system :(

All the following things I've already tried after googling:

- obviously Windows **auto-fix** boot feature didn't help
- I am unable to boot into **Safe Mode** --> also getting Inaccessible Boot Device bluescreen
- And `chkdsk /f` obviously also didn't find anything
- Booting with **logging** enabled didn't create the logfile at C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt
- reverting to **restore points** from 2018-01-17 and 2018-01-12 didn't help --> same bluescreen
- successfully uninstalled the pending security update using the following command: `dism /image:h: /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~15063.786.1.5` --> same bluescreen
- `sfc /scannow` didn't find any issues
- `bootrec /fixmbr` succeeds but didn't help
- `bootrec /fixboot` says **"Element not found."**
- `bootrec /rebuildbcd` does find my `C:\Windows` installation, but also fails with **"Element not found."** error
- `bcdedit` gives me the error: **"The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found."**

Is there anything else I can try before resetting my PC? Is there anything else I can look into why my windows just doesn't want to boot?

My desktop PC:

- Intel i5-6600 CPU
- MSI Z170A-G45 Gaming (7977-002R) mainboard
- MSI nvidia GTX 970
- Windows 10 Pro Version 1703 (OS build 15063) (according to regedit hive)

why do I get "Element not found." error on `bootrec` command? And the weird part is, in `diskpart` I can see a 100 MB volume next to my Windows volume, but it has NTFS and it's partition type is Primary (not system or something). Shouldn't the EFI boot volume be in FAT32?

EDIT: according to windows install usb stick, my SSD formatted as MBR :o 
Where and how can I verify that?

EDIT #2: just confirmed in `partdisk`. my SSD is partitioned with MBR.

Comment: I had this exact issue after the Fall Creator's Update: https://superuser.com/q/1229694/690483 You can try the instructions in the link to export and rebuild the BCD store, but sorry to say I did not find a solution and had to reinstall Windows...hope you have better luck.

Comment: thx, I have seen that link already, but `bcdedit` always fails on me. "The requested system device cannot be found." Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Update your question and include which security update(s) you installed.  15063.786 indicates you are 2 months behind on security updates and have not installed 1709.  "Shouldn't the EFI boot volume be in FAT32?" - Yes.  Verify you are looking at the correct partition, if you don't have a FAT32 partition, then you have no EFI partition.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't install any security updates manually. I was all windows doing. So I don't exactly know if I had Fall Creators Update installed or not. And how can I verify that I have MBR partition?

Comment: Your build makes it impossible for you to have installed 1709.  I didn’t say you had a MBR partition.

Comment: any ideas how i can solve bootrec and bcdedit errors mentioned in my question?

Comment: I just confirmed that my SSD is partitioned in MBR. does this change anything in how to solve my boot issues and why i'm getting errors on `bootrec` and `bcdedit`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You should keep drivers up to date. This blue screen error occurs when Windows can't access system partition correctly. It may be due to faulty hard disk or any other issues.

It seems the problem you are facing is due to a security update. So, you should uninstall the update. But, If you can't access your PC, follow these instructions.

- At first, Insert a bootable windows media on your PC and boot from it.
- Then, Click on Next and then click on Repair your computer.
- Go to Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt.
- Then, Run the following commands.

reg load HKLM\temp c:\windows\system32\config\software

reg delete "HKLM\temp\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\SessionsPending"/v Exclusive

reg unload HKLM\temp

dism /image:C:\ /get-packages

- It should show you the all installed and pending updates with the package names. Remember the pending package name. If there is nothing pending, remember the latest one.
- Now, Run the following command
  MKDIR C:\temp\packages
- After the run this command.

dism /image:c:\ /remove-package /packagename:PACKAGE-IDENTITY-NAME /scratchdir:c:\temp\packages

**Note: Replace PACKAGE-IDENTITY-NAME with the package name.**

Hopefully, It will fix INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

You can find some other fixes from here: https://www.xtremerain.com/fix-inaccessible-boot-device/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you include the information here? Links can change and the information can disappear. Also, at the moment this seems like self-promotion, since your user page suggests you run the linked blog.